# iOS leak from libllvmContainer.dylib

Tags: ios, llvm, llvm-clang

I don't know what the source of this could be.
But in instruments I see that it is growing after pushing and popping a certain view controller multiple times.

It doesn't seem like my view controller is the owner of this ,

Has anybody experienced this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does it show up as leaking when testing on a device or only on the simulator?